# SqlAlchemy ORM eager load an object's relationships

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a tree structure of ORM relationships that is (let's say) 4 levels deep. They are not eager loaded by default. I'm in a situation where I need to get a "copy" of a tree. So I have something like:

```
root = my_obj
for rel1 in root.some_relationship:
    for rel2 in rel1.some_other_relationship:
        ... etc ...
```

So, obviously, it's the classic "gotta go to the db to load each relationship" problem, and it's taking forever. I know that I can do an actual query to load the object in root.some_relationship with subqueryload (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.subqueryload), but if I already have a handle on root.some_relationship, can I tell that object to eager load a list of subrelationships?

```
root.some_relationship.eagerload('some_other_relationship.yet_another_rel')
```

would be my pseudocode for what I'm trying to do.

If not, and a query to get the object with its relationships already eager loaded like so:

```
obj = session.query(root.some_rel_fk_id).subqueryload(....)
```

is the best way, then that is totally cool.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading at query time is the best (maybe only, but never say never) way to do this.  However, your query example is wrong.  You specify loading in the `options` call:

```
root = session.query(MyModel
).options(subqueryload('my_rel').subqueryload('sub_rel'))
```